# How can I generate a spline curve using glm_gtx_spline::catmullRom?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have 4 points that I had do travel with the camera using a spline curve, how can I generate the curve using the glm::gtx_spline::catmullRom?

It is a function from glm_gtx_spline http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00203.html

```
genType catmullRom (genType const &v1, genType const &v2, genType const &v3, genType const &v4, typename genType::value_type const &s)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline has some description/pictures of control points.   You just give it the points you want it to base the curve on and tell it "how far" along the curve you want the value for.  There's no such thing as a "curve" to opengl, so you have to pick how many samples along the spline you want and call catmullRom that many times to get the samples.  The more times you call it the better it looks but the slower your code.

Comment: the "how far" bit is the last parameter.  The first 4 are the control points.

Comment: So, the control points are the points that I want to travel? And how can I set the how far bit?

Comment: I used like this: glm::vec3 test = glm::catmullRom(point1, point2, point3, point4, 1);, and it is returning me point3, this means that I have to travel that point now and after to point4?

Comment: The intermediary control points are the points that define the curve.  They arelikely not on the curve (look at the picture on the wikipedia link I gave you).  Say you want your "curve" to be 11 line segments - then you call this 11 times with "how far" at 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6....1.0   Though that's not going to give a very good curve since you'd want more detail in the curves and less in the straights.   Not sure how to generate better "how far"s

Comment: Let me see if I undestood this, point1 is the actual position, point2 is the destiny, point3 and point4 is the control points yes?

Comment: I would guess 4 is the destination -- but just play with them, it should become obvious quickly based on your results.  At "how far"=1 just see what point you get -- that's the destination and how far=0 is the start. -- I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111947/discussion-between-matheus-weber-and-xaxxon).

Answer (score 6):

A Catmull-Rom spline generally consists of several segments that each interpolate one pair of successive control points. The `glm::catmullRom` function computes only one **segment** of this curve, which depends on four successive control points (`p0`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`). The curve segment always goes from `p1` to `p2`, while the points `p0` and `p3` only affect how the curve bends in between, as illustrated here:

[image: Catmull-Rom curve segment]
(image by Hadunsford - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=28956755)

By chaining several of these curve segments in sequence, you create a Catmull-Rom spline that interpolates a sequence of (an arbitrary number of) control points. If each Catmull-Rom curve segment is computed from four successive control points, the resulting spline will be continuous and smooth (C<sup>1</sup> continuous).

Given a vector `cp` of *n* control points, the following function computes the value of the Catmull-Rom spline at parameter `t` (where `t` goes from 0 to *n*-1):

```
glm::vec3 catmull_rom_spline(const std::vector<glm::vec3>& cp, float t)
{
    // indices of the relevant control points
    int i0 = glm::clamp<int>(t - 1, 0, cp.size() - 1);
    int i1 = glm::clamp<int>(t,     0, cp.size() - 1);
    int i2 = glm::clamp<int>(t + 1, 0, cp.size() - 1);
    int i3 = glm::clamp<int>(t + 2, 0, cp.size() - 1);

    // parameter on the local curve interval
    float local_t = glm::fract(t);

    return glm::catmullRom(cp[i0], cp[i1], cp[i2], cp[i3], local_t);
}
```

In this implementation, the relevant control point indices are clamped to the range (0, *n*-1). Conceptually, this achieves a doubling of the first and last control points which has the effect that the first and last control point of `cp` are also interpolated.

Varying the parameter `t` between 0 and *n*-1 will now trace out points on a smooth curve interpolating all points in `cp`.